# Problem with calculating a definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this function $$f_{h}(x) = r^{-1/2} \mathcal{X}_{(0,r]}(x) - r^{1/2}h^{-1}\mathcal{X}_{(r+h,r+2h]}(x)$$ with $r>0$ and $h>0$.
One of the things that the exercise asks me is to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{h}(x)^{2} dx$ but I have managed to obtain that correctly and it is $1 + \frac{r}{h}$
But now I need to calculate this
$$\int_{0}^{x} f_{h}(t)dt $$
I think it should be divided into 3 integrals where '$t$' moves between $(0,r],(r,r+h],(r+h,r+2h]$.
But I can't come up with the correct solution.
In case it helps you, the correct solution is the following:
$$\int_{0}^{x} f_{h}(t)dt = xr^{-1/2} \mathcal{X}_{(0,r]}(x) + r^{1/2}\mathcal{X}_{(r,r+h]}(x) + [r^{1/2}-r^{1/2}h^{-1}(x-r-h)]\mathcal{X}_{(r+h,r+2h]}(x)$$

Could you help me get there?

Comment: Is $\chi$ any function or characteristic function?

Comment: Characteristic function. So I do not understand what appears in the solution of the integral.